Adding bookmarks or something similar to a PDF-file in VS Code
I was wondering if anyone knows how to add something like bookmarks or smoothscrolls to a pdf-file that can be read in Visual Studio Code?
I have seen some pdf-files in VS that have like a menu on the left-hand side with headlines, that can make you jump to that section in the pdf when you click on them. Is that something you do in the pdf-file or in VS, and how do you do it? I'm completely lost here, I have no idea where to even begin.
